# how does screenshot works? is it due to the hardware that supports or the software which pile ups the pixel?

Tags: screenshot, hardware

Can someone answer how does the screenshot works? irrespective of mobile phone  or PC? I've tried to look for the answer all over the internet but every where i can find only the videos how to take screenshot? But none of them gives me the result. Does that relates to software which buffers and converts the screen-content to image?

Comment: How is this related to programming?

Comment: hardware could do it yes.  software could make a copy of the framebuffer yes.  software could re-create/build the frame to a different output, yes.  And perhaps other ways.  Does every device do it one and only one way, nope.  There is no general answer here.  Can a device change how it does it from one software/firmware update to another?  yes, so even if you told us what device you have we still might not know, if we even knew as we dont have access to most devices internals software or hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Irrespective of hardware or software in computers or smartphones, there is something called a "frame buffer" that stores all of the pixels currently displayed on the screen as numbers. A screenshot is essentially a dump of all of those numbers into a file, with more numbers tacked on the front to cause a computer to interpret them as a particular type of image.